# How to copy file from latest directory, but if it doesn't exist check the next latest directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Would like some help with this. I'm a total beginner.

Example:

```
c:\folder a\folder b3\folder c\
c:\folder a\folder b2\folder c\file.txt
c:\folder a\folder b1\folder c\file.txt
```

Procedure:

- check for `file.txt` in "`...folder b3\folder c\`" -> file doesn't exist
- check for `file.txt` in next latest folder -> "`...\folder b2\folder c\file.txt`" does exist
- copy the file and place it in `c:\my docs\`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some logic to do this. A very simple example, below, does exactly what you're looking for from the question and nothing else. You'd be best off expanding it in to a function so that you can use it with other folders and files, and this could certainly be simplified but I wrote it out verbose so that you can see what is going on and learn. For instance, you could easily combine the foreach loop in to the while loop or not use some of the variables.

This uses only the basics from PowerShell, so if you're not sure what is going on search around for any of the resources that can help.

```
#define the variables for the things that don't change
$root = "C:\folder a\"
$subfolder = "\folder c\"
$filename = "file.txt"
$destination = "c:\my docs\"

#add the folders you want to cycle through to an array, and you'll be checking b3 first here
$folders = @("folder b3", "folder b2", "folder b1")

#make an empty array that will hold the full paths that we're going to create
$fullPaths = @()

#add the combined path to a list
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $fullPaths += $root + $folder +  $subfolder + $filename
}

#Loop through each item in folders, and stop when you find one that has the file.
$i = 0
while ($i -lt $fullPaths.Count) {
    #find out if the item exists and put that in a variable
    $exists = Test-Path $fullPaths[$i]
    if ($exists){
        #if the result of the test is true, copy the item and break the while loop to not go any further
        Copy-Item -Path $fullPaths[$i] -Destination $destination
        break
    }
    #make sure to increment the $i so that the while loop doesn't get stuck and run for ever
    $i++
}
```

Comment: new folders are being added daily, so I am unable to just add the folders I want to cycle through.

I need something that will scan the folder and sort them by highest value, then search the highest value folder etc

Answer (score 0):

If the .txt file always has the same name you can use this code

```
$src = Get-ChildItem "C:\folder a\*\folder c\file.txt"
$i=0
foreach ($file in $src)
{
    $i++
    Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "c:\my docs\file$i.txt" -Force 
}
```

Comment: This is almost what im looking for, except its copying the file from the oldest folder....."folder b1"  from my example